# Why I can not include the header

Tags: c++

I can't contain the header in another header files, but I can contain it in a .cpp file.

```
#include "Version_test.h"
```

I put this same sentence in Screen.h and main.cpp, error in Screen.h but success in main.cpp.

Actually I put the header Version_test.h in the current folder, as the third picture showed. I don't know why......

[image: Version_test.h is in the right place]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: You should do `#include "Version_test.h"`, not `#include "Version_test"`.

Comment: `#include "Version_test"` => `#include "Version_test.h"`? The file extension matters.

Comment: Add the ".h" extension to the filename.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code. Create a verbatim text copy.

Comment: your `"` look not correct and the name of the header has to match. Maybe you got confused by the standard headers getting included without extension. They have no extension. The name of the header is `string`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I correct it to be #include "Version_test.h" but the problem is still there.....The problem is in the .cpp it can be detected, but in .h can't.

Comment: Have you told the compiler where Version_test.h lives? Either put its directory path in the `-I` include path or add the path in the `#include` statement

Comment: what is the error compiler is taking?

Answer (score 2):

Include the header using the `.h` file extension.

Comment: I correct it but the problem is still there.

Comment: Make sure the header file that you are including the "version_test.h" file is in same directory as the file "version_test.h" file

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the include path.
The header where you added the *.h gets included in multiple files.
What error came up when you start compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually find out what's wrong. I ctrl+c "Version_test.h" and ctrl+v it firstly in my VS2017 and secondly in the current folder. Actually in VS2017, I add the "Version_test.h" which comes from its original path, but not the one in my current folder......

Anyway thank you all, for your enthusiastic help to me.